# How can MeasureSpec.getMode() extract a mode from an integer value?

Tags: java, android, view, onmeasure

I'm on chapter 4 of Professional Android 4 Application Development, and it's telling me that both a size value *and* a mode are extracted from the widthMeasureSpec and heightMeasureSpec values passed to the onMeasure() method of a custom view.  Would those not have to be some other data structure than an integer primitive to accomplish this?  Are these integers encoded in such a way that it would be possible to ever manually override their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mode is either EXACTLY, AT_MOST, or UNSPECIFIED.  So technically it only takes two bits to store the mode.  If you look at their values, EXACTLY is 0x80000000, AT_MOST is 0x40000000 and UNSPECIFIED is 0x00000000.  They are taking the top two bits of the int and ORing them with the size to get the MeasureSpec.  This is probably a holdover from early Android when devices *really* didn't have a lot of memory, so they tried to conserve wherever they could.

Comment: Thank you, that answers the question perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, I did a double-take when I first saw MeasureSpec too, so I looked at the code to see what was going on -- which is how I could answer your question.